# Reorder html elements in dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a list of elements:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="abc"></div>
    <div class="abc"></div>
    <div class="abc"></div>
</div>
```

And I have an array or numbers which represent new order:

```
var arr = [2,1,0];
```

I would like to reposition these abc divs to new positions inside parent wrapper.

Important thing is that abc divs have events and data attached to them and this needs to be preserved!

I have came up with this and it seems to be working as expected:

```
var wrapper = $('.wrapper'), items = wrapper.children('div.abc');

var orderedItems = $.map(arr, function(value) {
    return $(items).clone(true,true).get(value);
});
wrapper.empty().html(orderedItems);
```

I wanted to make sure this is the right way.

I could do with javascript solution as well if possible.

Comment: for the record, jQuery is a Framework written *in Javascript* which means what you've got *is a Javascript solution*

Comment: If it's working, then it works! You also might look into re-ordering using CSS with flexbox and `order`: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_order.asp

Answer (score 8, accepted):

no need to copy all items .. twice

```
var wrapper = $('.wrapper'), 
    items = wrapper.children('.abc'),
    arr = [2,1,0];

//items.detach(); if arr doesn't reuse all items
wrapper.append( $.map(arr, function(v){ return items[v] }) );
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by copy twice. I have tried your example, this does not copy events which I mentioned in my original post. (that is why I used jquery clone). I am missing something?

Comment: Please show the exact code aou use and explain what particularly doesn't work. The Point in my code is, that it creates an intermediate Array of the actual DOM-Nodes in the correct order, and appends them to the wrapper. By adding the DOM-Node to a (new) parent it is first removed from the node it was in, and then added to the new one. No Node is cloned, no references/Events/Properties/anything changed, only the Position in the DOM-Tree.

Comment: BY Copy twice i mean: first you create a clone of the current Node, and afaik $.html() this converts it into the string representation and parses this string-representation again (where again the Nodes are basically cloned).

Answer (score 22):

If you want a pure Javascript solution (no jQuery involved)

```
var arr = [2,1,0];
var wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper");
var items = wrapper[0].children;
var elements = document.createDocumentFragment();

arr.forEach(function(idx) {
    elements.appendChild(items[idx].cloneNode(true));
});

wrapper[0].innerHTML = null;
wrapper[0].appendChild(elements);
```

A little improvement of my previous answer. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jltorresm/1ukhzbg2/2/

Comment: Please, please use Document Fragments to carry batches of items around

Comment: You are right Thomas, changed my answer to use document fragments

Comment: But doing in this way I will lose all event listeners attached to the element, cloneNode won't carry any listeneres

Comment: does the `documentFragment` itself show up as a parent element when you append it to the document?

Answer (score 14):

Keep in mind that when you add an element that is already in the DOM, this element will be moved, not copied.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/balvin/pen/VBBqeV)

```js
let wrapper=document.querySelector(".wrapper");
let children=wrapper.children;
let newOrder=[3,2,1,0];
//it means that the first element you want it to be the four element
//The second element you want it to be the third
//the third element you want it to be the second
//the four element you want it to be the first
for(let i=0;i<newOrder.length;i++){
  for(let j=0;j<newOrder.length;j++){
    if(i==newOrder[j]){
      wrapper.appendChild(children[j]);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>a</div>
  <div>b</div>
  <div>c</div>
  <div>d</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

I know this is an old question, but google lead me to it.
There is a sub property on flexbox (css) called 'order', that allow you to choose the order that elements are displayed. Is possible to use javascript to change this sub property and reorder the displayed elements.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_order.asp

Edit 1 - code example:

```
<style>
 .wrapper {
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: column;
 }
</style>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="abc">One</div>
  <div class="abc">Tow</div>
  <div class="abc">Three</div>
</div>
<button id="reorder" type="button">Reorder</button>
<button id="unreorder" type="button">Unreorder</button>

<script>
var reorderButton = document.querySelector('#reorder');
var unreorderButton = document.querySelector('#unreorder');
var abcDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.abc');
var newOrder = [2, 1, 0];

reorderButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  abcDivs.forEach(function(element, index) {
    element.style.order = newOrder[index];
  });
});
unreorderButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  abcDivs.forEach(function(element, index) {
    element.style.order = null;
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: It would be good to provide an example that applies to the question, in addition to the w3schools link.

Comment: This is a great, simple suggestion for doing this in cases when you can use flexbox. Thanks!

Comment: Good suggestion

Comment: Neat idea.  Your tip is much appreciated

Comment: The specification, and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items), explicitly recommend against using this kind of trick (except when the reordering is purely visual and has no semantics): “If you are using a reverse value, or otherwise reordering your items, you should consider whether you actually need to change the logical order in the source. The specification continues with a warning not to use reordering to fix issues in your source”

Comment: This solution will not be accessibly compliant, it breaks the tabbing order vs visual order and will not work great for some screen readers.

Answer (score 4):

This solution works better for me, we build an array of elements (`[...wrapper.children]`) then we use `.sort` based on a model ([5,4,3,2,1,0]) and then we use appendChild. Since the elements are the same as the originals, the event listeners remain working fine. Here the code:

```js
//this is just to add event listeners
[...document.getElementsByClassName("abc")].forEach(e =>
  e.addEventListener("click", ev => console.log(ev.target.innerText))
);

var wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper")[0];
var items = [...wrapper.children];

const newOrder = [5,4,3,2,1,0]

items.sort((a, b)=>newOrder.indexOf(items.indexOf(a)) - newOrder.indexOf(items.indexOf(b)));

items.forEach(it=>wrapper.appendChild(it));
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="abc">0</div>
  <div class="abc">1</div>
  <div class="abc">2</div>
  <div class="abc">3</div>
  <div class="abc">4</div>
  <div class="abc">5</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, if you click on 0, 1, etc, the event listener works.

Answer (score 0):

After reading through the others' solutions, I've created a simple bit of code to reverse elements such as `div`s or or `li`s that are wrapped in a single container element.

```
// Select all divs which need to be reordered
const items = document.querySelectorAll("#plan-carousel .plans-carousel .column-holder")
// Create an array of the divs and reverse them
const reverseItems = Array.from(items).reverse()
// Select the parent or wrapper element
const wrapper = document.querySelector("#plan-carousel .plans-carousel")
// Iterate over the reversed array and append each one to the parent element
reverseItems.forEach(item => wrapper.appendChild(item))
```

**References:**

1. According to the [MDN's `appendChild()` article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild): If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document, appendChild() moves it from its current position to the new position.

In other words, since these items already exist, when we append them they are simply moved rather than duplicated.