# Re-order html elements in multiple columns (From one column to another)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html structure

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="column-1">
        <div class="box" id="box-1"></div>
        <div class="box" id="box-2"></div>
        <div class="box" id="box-3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="column-2">
        <div class="box" id="box-4"></div>
        <div class="box" id="box-5"></div>
        <div class="box" id="box-6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I have two arrays of numbers

```
arr1 = [2, 4, 3]
arr2 = [1, 5, 6]
```

I would like to re-position `.box` divs to given position.

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685316/reorder-html-elements-in-dom), but that only works with single column

```
var wrapper = jQuery('.column-1'), 
    items = wrapper.children('.box'),
    arr = [2,1,0];
wrapper.append( jQuery.map(arr, function(v){ return items[v] }) );
```

I can't figure out how to do this, with jquery or javascript!

Expected output is

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="column-1">
        <div class="box" id="box-2"></div>
        <div class="box" id="box-4"></div>
        <div class="box" id="box-3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="column-2">
        <div class="box" id="box-1"></div>
        <div class="box" id="box-5"></div>
        <div class="box" id="box-6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want short your HTML or HTML content?

Comment: @jishansiddique hey, I want to sort .box divs like the expected output shown above!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, yes, my bad! First of all, I forgot to add `function` in front of `reorderElements`. Second, I didn't realize that the values in the two arrays could be in either column. This makes things a little bit more complex, but we can rely on jQuery's magic to get to our goal.

I've tested the following snippet and it seems to do what you expect:

```js
function findElement(parent, number) {
  return parent.find('#box-' + number);
}

function reorderElements() {
    const arr1 = [2, 4, 3];
    const arr2 = [1, 5, 6];
    const col1 = jQuery('.column-1');
    const col2 = jQuery('.column-2');
    col1.append(
        arr1.map(function(value) {
          const col1Elem = findElement(col1, value);
          const col2Elem = findElement(col2, value);
          return col1Elem[0] || col2Elem[0];
        })
    );
    col2.append(
        arr2.map(function(value) {
          const col1Elem = findElement(col1, value);
          const col2Elem = findElement(col2, value);
          return col1Elem[0] || col2Elem[0];
        })
    );
}

reorderElements();
```

This code can most definitively optimized, but it does the job!

You can run the code live on CodePen: https://codepen.io/yvesgurcan/pen/gOOEvxr.

Comment: Thank you so much! You're a true life saver! ✨❤

Comment: No problem! I hope that the code makes sense to you.

Comment: Yes, it totally does! And I never thought this could be done with this efficiency!

Comment: Perfect! I'm sure that if you dig deeper, you'll find ways to refactor this code. Let me know if you have other questions!

Comment: Yeah sure! Thanks again✌

Answer (score 0):

Given that you found code that works for one column, it looks like you're almost there! You can slightly tweak the answer from the other question you linked by creating a function:

```js
reorderElements(parent, arr) {
    const wrapper = jQuery(parent);
    const items = wrapper.children('.box');
    wrapper.append(
        jQuery.map(arr, function(value) { return items[value] })
    );
}

const arr1 = [2, 4, 3]
const arr2 = [1, 5, 6]
reorderElements('.column-1', arr1);
reorderElements('.column-2', arr2);
```

I've also updated the code to use `const` and semi-colons.

What do you think? Does that code do what you expect?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but I tested it on my elements and it's not sorting them! Have you tested this with my snippet?