# Use Javascript to Manipulate String

Tags: javascript, regex

Change the string from this:

```
var string = '<p>test black text</p><p><span style="color: #3598db;">test blue text</span></p>';
```

To this:

```
var string = '<p><span style="color: #3598db;">test blue text</span></p><p>test black text</p>';
```

I have an HTML text field, and I am trying to put any text that has color at the top of the text field. Thank you for the help.

```
let text = '<p>test black text</p><p><span style="color: #3598db;">test blue text</span></p>'
let regex = /^<p><span style="color: #3598db;">(.*?)<\/p>/m.exec(text);
```

Comment: "*text with color*" - what does that mean? Coloured text or text that contains the name of a colour?

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685316/reorder-html-elements-in-dom?

Comment: Any special reason this needs to be done with a regular expression? If this running in a browser then DOM manipulation probably would be easier.

Comment: @RoToRa I am developing in ServiceNow and can't use DOM manipulation. I am trying to adjust text in an HTML text field

Comment: Manipulating HTML using regexen is notoriously difficult and error prone. It’s certainly *possible* for simple cases, but it’s also very possible to throw HTML at that regex that it will choke on.

Comment: @deceze I agree. I have a unique use case that I am testing and running out of ideas

Comment: Despite whats said in the comments, html or xml or sgml tags are parse able entirely by Regular Expressions. What is not a tag is content. SAX is one example. Consequently, I can give you a regex to move the tag to the front of the string. Tell me the tag and what stand alone attribute or attr / value (s) you need that uniquely identifies it .

Comment: `^([\S\s]*?)(<p\s*>\s*<span(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\sstyle\s*=\s*(?:(['"])\s*color:[\S\s]*?\3))\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]*?)+>[\S\s]*?<\/span\s*>\s*<\/p\s*>)`
Substitute `$2$1` https://regex101.com/r/MUB9KQ/1  Remember though, although tag parsing is reliable, there are caveats when it comes to tag matching spanning content. A multitude of other things not mentioned as well.

Comment: @sln [RegExp is not appropriate to parse non-arbitrary html.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @evolutionxbox, what is, _"non-arbitrary html"_?

Comment: @sln Nobody said that matching individual start or end tags is not possible with regular expressions. The problem is with parsing/validating whole documents, and manipulating html according to its *structure*. Your proposed solution does not handle nested paragraphs correctly, for example.

Comment: @Reilas sorry I meant arbitrary HTML. i.e. not a limited known set of HTML.

Answer (score -1):

> *"... I have an HTML text field, and I am trying to put any text that has color at the top of the text field. ..."*

Use a *regular expression pattern* to match the *p*, and *span*, tags.

```
/<p\s*><span\s.*?style\s*=\s*['"].*?color:.+?<\/span\s*><\/p\s*>/gs
```

For each match, prepend *s* with the match, and remove the initial value.
Realistically, the *replace* method might not be the best choice; it's just an example.

```js
let s = '<p>test black text</p><p><span style="color: #3598db;">test blue text</span></p>'
let p = /<p\s*><span\s.*?style\s*=\s*['"].*?color:.+?<\/span\s*><\/p\s*>/gs
let m
while (m = p.exec(s)) s = m[0] + s.replace(m[0], '')

console.log(s)
```

Comment: That does not handle nested elements correctly.